# Regular expression: numbers spaces parentheses +

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression where any number is allowed with spaces, parentheses and hyphens in any order. But there **must** be a "+" (plus sign) at the end.

Comment: What is a 'parent` in text, please? EDIT: Ah, "parentheses", now I get it :)

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: What is a "number"? `123`? `3.14159`? `+1.2E-4`?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the regex:

```
^[\d() -]+\+$
```

Explanation:

```
^   : Start anchor
[   : Start of char class.
 \d : Any digit
 (  : A literal (. No need to escape it as it is non-special inside char class.
 )  : A literal )
    : A space
 -  : A hyphen. To list a literal hyphen in char class place it at the beginning
      or at the end without escaping it or escape it and place it anywhere.
]   : End of char class
+   : One or more of the char listed in the char class.
\+  : A literal +. Since a + is metacharacter we need to escape it.
$   : End anchor
```

Comment: Excellent answer and explanation. If I could up-vote twice, I would.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I came for the quick fix and left with knowledge.

Comment: Wow I understand regex now!

Answer (score 1):

If the rules mean that the whole string must be according to them, then:

```
/^[\d\(\)\- ]+\+$/
```

This will match (i) `435 (345-325) +` but not (ii) `my phone is 435 (345-325)+, remember it`.

If you want to just extract (i) from (ii) you could use my original RegExp:

```
/[\d\(\)\- ]+\+/
```

Comment: If `+` should be at the and, shouldn't there be a `$` at the end?

Comment: That kind of depends how you interpret the question - without the `$` the `+` will be at the end of the match. But fair enough, I added it.

Comment: This will also match `foo123+`